# do promises behave differently in services vrs controllers?

Tags: angularjs, service, promise

So I am pretty stuck. I have used angular promises within controllers before similar to this:

```
thisCtrl.someFunction = function (data){
   //...
}

ApiCall.get.something().then(function(data){
   thisCtrl.newData = data;
   thisCtrl.someFunction(thisCtrl.newData);
});
```

and I have been able to then use thisCtrl.newData (created within the promise) throughout the controller. I have also been able to use functions defined outside of the promise, within the promise - as shown in the above ex.

For some reason when trying to do this in a service I cant seem to make it work. Trying to use the same pattern as above:

```
this.someFunction = function (data){
   //...
}

ApiCall.get.something().then(function(data){
   this.newData = data; // Cannot read property of 'newData' of undefined
   this.someFunction(thisCtrl.newData); //error: Cannot read property of 'someFunctions' of undefined
});
```

So it seems that once I do the same thing in the service, this, is out of scope - rendering me kind of helpless in passing that data around to the rest of the service, or using any data from the rest of the service inside the promise. I have tried returning the data as an object:

```
ApiCall.get.something().then(function(data){
    return {
       data: data
    }
});
```

But it too returns a promise, leaving me in the same boat. I have actually tried a LOT of things, and googled quite a bit. I want this to be available in a service to prevent repeating large blocks of code in multiple controllers. Can I not create promises inside of services? If so, any help is appreciated as to how to properly do it.... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use "this", it may not be what you expect because "this" depends on the function context.

To make sure you're binding to the right function context use "fn.bind(this)"

```
ApiCall.get.something().then(function(data){
       this.newData = data;
       this.someFunction(...);
}.bind(this));
```

Alternatively, for wider cross-browser compatibility, you can save "this" as "self" in the outer function scope, so that you can use it from your inner function:

```
var self = this;
ApiCall.get.something().then(function(data){
       self.newData = data;
       self.someFunction(...);
});
```

For more information, check out this reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49872/using-var-self-this-or-bindthis

Comment: the var self on the outside worked for me. I tried it before but managed to do it wrong somehow. Thanks! I will try the bind next time too!